# Error in .htaccess File with Auto prepend + ErrorDocument + options

Tags: php, .htaccess, errordocument

i have this `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /server/403.php
php_value auto_prepend_file "./server/conferror.php"
```

but it send me this error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required './server/conferror.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

if i Remove `ErrorDocument` Line it work good.
if i set `ErrorDocument`, and remove `Options` Line it Work Fine but not block Directory navigation...

this File is a handler for php error that need to be prepend via `.htaccess` `php_value auto_prepend_file "./server/conferror.php"`

How can i make work from `.htaccess` prevent navigation directory and ouput to file `ErrorDocument` at same time and Preserve the prepend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soved with this code:

```
# Control de Errores
php_value auto_prepend_file "server/conferror.php"
# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes
# Hide the contents of directories
IndexIgnore *
# Hide files of type .png, .zip, .jpg, .gif and .doc from listing
IndexIgnore *.png *.zip *.jpg *.gif *.doc *.pdf *.txt *.jpeg *.log
# Allow access to php files
<Files *.log>
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files signal.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
# Mal Request
ErrorDocument 400 server/400.html
# No Autorizado
ErrorDocument 401 server/401.html
# Acceso Prohibido
ErrorDocument 403 server/403.html
# No Encontrada
ErrorDocument 404 server/404.html
# Error interno del Servidor
ErrorDocument 500 server/500.html
```